# MPI does not run with requested number of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, posix

I am trying to run the following example MPI code that launches 20 threads and keeps those threads busy for a while. However, when I check the CPU utilization using a tool like *nmon* or *top* I see that only a single thread is being used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int provided, rank;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
    if (provided != MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED)
        exit(1);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    auto f = [](float x) {
        float result = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < x; i++) { result += 10 * i + x; }
        cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
    };

    thread threads[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        threads[i] = thread(f, 100000000.f); // do some work
    for (auto& th : threads) 
        th.join();

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code using *mpicxx*: `mpicxx -std=c++11 -pthread example.cpp -o example` and run it using *mpirun*: `mpirun -np 1 example`.

I am using Open MPI version 4.1.4 that is compiled with posix thread support (following the explanation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563438/mpi-with-multiple-pthreads)).

```bash
$ mpicxx --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.4
$ ompi_info | grep -i thread
Thread support: posix (MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: yes, OPAL support: yes, OMPI progress: no, ORTE progress: yes, Event lib: yes)
   FT Checkpoint support: no (checkpoint thread: no)
$ mpicxx -std=c++11 -pthread example.cpp -o example
$ ./example
```

My CPU has 10 cores and 20 threads and runs the [example code above without MPI](https://pastebin.com/PFqa5Bms) on all 20 threads. So, why does the code with MPI not run on all threads?

I suspect I might need to do something with *MPI bindings*, which I see being mentioned in some answers on the same topic ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56718527/6908550), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42308642/6908550)), but [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42308642/6908550) entirely exclude these options, so I'm unsure whether this is the correct approach.

Comment: I googled mpirun and it said this: "If your application uses threads, then you probably want to ensure that you are either not bound at all (by specifying --bind-to none), or bound to multiple cores using an appropriate binding level or specific number of processing elements per application process. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpirun -np 1 ./example` assigns a single core to your program (so 20 threads end up time sharing): this is the default behavior for Open MPI (e.g. 1 core per MPI process when running with `-np 1` or `-np 2`.

`./example` (e.g. singleton mode) should use all the available cores, unless you are already running on a subset.

If you want to use all the available cores with `mpirun`, you can

```
mpirun --bind-to none -np 1 ./example
```